# php timer to an event without user action

Tags: php, datetime, timer

I am writing a web app in php that requires to count upto 24 hours after a user registers in the system then perfom an action. I want the user to sign up into the application and after 24 hours, perfom an action like send an email saying "you are one day old". this should happen automatically wihout the user perfoming any action on the app. Any idea on how I might go about this?

Comment: why you not using cron jobs... for this...

Comment: if you are using linux os, then use cronjob, or if it is windows server then use task scheduler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usualy on the server im using **crone** . so just check if the user have date registered +24 hours and then send email.